# How to restrict the spring integration to read the specific directory path only?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-dsl, spring-batch-job-monitoring

Currently, I am using the FileReadingMessageSource to read files from specific directory using Spring Integration.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File(/temp));
    source.setFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    source.setUseWatchService(true);
    source.setWatchEvents(WatchEventType.CREATE);
    return source;
}
```

Problem, I am facing is the configuration above is able to read the files from temp folder and also other folders inside temp folder. For example - If I create a folder inside the temp like temp/csvfolder and place csv file inside csvfolder, still its able to poll the file .

**Can we restrict it to specific folder only?**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the watch service, it will only look at the top level.

If you want to use a watch service you would need to implement a custom `DirectoryScanner`.